# Getting current environment of iPhone app

Tags: iphone, runtime, titanium-mobile, environment

I'm developing an iPhone app using Titanium Studio Alloy. In config.json file, I see that there are three environment as follows:

```
  "env:development": 
  {

  }, 
  "env:test": 
  {

  }, 
  "env:production": 
  {

  }
```

is there any way that I could alert the current environment so that I could get an idea of what environment my app is in.

Answer (score 2):

[`Ti.App.deployType`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App-property-deployType) should answer your Question.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found a way to get it. There is no inbuild function or property to get it. But, instead I set a variable namely currentEnv and set its value to the environment name. Below is the code for your reference:

```
  "env:development": 
  {
      currentEnv: "Development"
  }, 
  "env:test": 
  {
      currentEnv: "Test"
  }, 
  "env:production": 
  {
      currentEnv: "Production"
  }
```

Now I could alert it as follows:

```
alert("The current environment is " + Alloy.CFG.currentEnv);
```

Hope it would help someone out there.